# Is it a good idea to have a "fat" MySQL table? If not, what are some good ways to thin it?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that contains 70+ columns. It's pretty fat, but I don't know if it's fat enough that it'll affect performance.

Alternatively I can concatenate some values to reduce it down to around 30, but updating can be harder. If the performance is not an issue with this many columns, I don't want to change the structure.

Currently I plan to have more than 500 rows to be inserted. It can go up to, say, 2000.

My current setup:

```
Row #| field 1 | field 2 | ... | field 70+
------------------------------------------
ID1  | int     | int     | ... | int
ID2  | int     | int     | ... | int
:
:
:
```

One way I can think of to make the table thinner:

```
Row #| cat field 1                             | cat field 2  | ...
------------------------------------------------------------------
ID1  |string containing int's from field 1 to 7| int's 8 to 14| ...
```

But part of the operation is to move one field's value to another periodically. Say moving `field 1` to `field 2`, all I need to do is

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `field 2` = `field 1`
WHERE `ROW #` = ID1;
```

but having a string would require more operations to delimit the string, change the values, and then out them back into the string again. I don't know if this is worth it.

Is this 70+ column table viable? Is there a better idea to make the table thinner?

I use Python outside of MySQL commands, so if you have some ideas how to operate this in Python, it'd be really helpful.

Comment: Is your data reasonably normalized?

Comment: If you only plan on have 500-2000 rows, I don't think it matters. If you were planning on an order of magnitude or more, then I'd suggest trying to breakup the table into multiple tables (provided that the relationship makes sense to be broken up), or making an index on the "hotter" columns.

Comment: The Python question is a bit vague and you're unlikely to get good answers by tacking it on to this question.  Python programming against MySQL is a well-defined subject so I suggest that you do some reading and come back with any specific issues as new questions.

Comment: every column is a calculation based on date (ex. average # of users one day ago, two days ago, etc.) I want to be able to store this info so that my API can query it fast. Yes, there are gonna be some zeroes, but I wouldn't consider this table sparse. I doubt this table is going to have more than 2000 rows honestly, unless some of our engineers decide to go haywire and create bunch of rows. Rows are not normally generated automatically based on new inputs.

Answer (score 1):

70 columns is a lot, but it shouldn't be a performance issue. It is much more likely to be an ergonomics issue for whoever is using the database, and on that basis I would try to reorganize.

There's got to be some way to thematically organize those 70 fields into several linked tables, or structure this data some other way. But without knowing anything about the data, it's hard to suggest anything more specific.

I would definitely recommend *against* consolidating values into text strings as you have proposed in order to cut down the number of columns. You will rue the day you made that change, I'd put money on it.